# Match equivalent to FindNext

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data sheet that I need to search for lines that meet two criteria (an ID number and date).

I have written a macro using `Find` and `FindNext` that will search the data for the ID number and every time it finds a match, it with then compare the date and return the line details if both cells match.

However, it is very slow to run and I've read that the `Match` function is much quicker. As far as I can see `Match` will only return the first matching value, is there any way to use `Match` to find subsequent matches?

Comment: Find and FindNext should be very quick unless you have many matches. Autofilter is probably a beter fit to your problem.. Match can be used to find later matches by changing the area being searched, but I suggest you post some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog post here with VBA code comparing the speed of Find, MATCH and using a variant array
http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/